# Is it possible for emacs to appear on right side of the desktop area when invoking it from the command line?

Tags: gnome, programming, emacs

My standard programming mode is to have a bash shell open on the left side of my desktop and to have emacs open on the right side. However, when I type emacs "filename" in to my shell, it comes up on the left side by default. Anyway I can change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straightforward to do this (even though it should be on the right side by default): all you need to do is to experiment with the `--geometry` option when launching a file. Apart from specifying the size of the `emacs` window, you can specify offsets to determine window position. It is well explained [at the official site](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Size-X.html):

> In the ‘--geometry’ option, {+-} means either a plus sign or a minus sign. A plus sign before xoffset means it is the distance from the left side of the screen; a minus sign means it counts from the right side. A plus sign before yoffset means it is the distance from the top of the screen, and a minus sign there indicates the distance from the bottom.

So, if we want to launch emacs top-right, we run:

```
emacs file.txt --geometry '-3+3'
```

Other options such as bottom-left would be `'+3-3'`, etc.

You could just put the above line in your `.bashrc` as an alias if you want it to launch it like this everytime:

```
alias emacs='emacs --geometry '-3+3''
```

After adding the alias, you have to run `. .bashrc` to source your `.bashrc` or restart the terminal for it to take effect.

(At any point you can launch `emacs` with `command emacs` to run it as normal and the alias will be ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

Various programs respect or disrespect the -geometry flag. Mik's solution happens to not work for me, though your mileage may vary. If it doesn't work for you, you could install the devilspie package. Then make a `~/.devilspie` directory and make a file `~/.devilspie/emacs.ds` with this content:

```
( if
  ( matches ( application_name ) "emacs" )
  ( begin    
    ( focus )
    (geometry "755x970+840+0")
  )
)
```

You will of course have to edit the numbers in `(geometry "755x970+840+0")` to something appropriate for your monitor resolution.

Finally, go to `Applications>Other>Startup Applications` and add `devilspie` to the programs to run upon startup.

Although this adds an extra dependency, this allows you to have one unified system for controlling the placement of all your applications, (e.g. gnome-terminal, firefox, etc), without having to learn/fight with each application's -geometry or configuration quirks. `devilspie` also works well with a variety of window managers.

Comment: Interesting, the geometry option with the offsets did work for me with `emacs` (as described in my answer), although, as you say, sometimes programs can ignore the flag.